# VoidSigner cannot sign transactions

Tags: nft, hardhat, mint

I'm trying to implement lazy mint functionality using the [CALM](https://github.com/nftstory/CALM) framwork  as an additional feature to my contracts.  The rest of my project is written in js, so I'm attempting to convert the typescript test methods over to js.   (Using Hardhat for testing)

I'm getting this when attempting to claim the NFT as a buyer.

> Error: VoidSigner cannot sign transactions
> (operation="signTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION,
> version=abstract-signer/5.5.0)

The contract is unchanged from [CALM721.sol](https://github.com/nftstory/CALM/blob/main/contracts/CALM721.sol)

The claim function, so you don't have to go look it up:

```
/**
 * @notice Call this function to buy a not yet minted NFT
 * @param permit The MintPermit signed by the NFT creator
 * @param recipient The address that will receive the newly minted NFT
 * @param v The v portion of the secp256k1 permit signature
 * @param r The r portion of the secp256k1 permit signature
 * @param s The s portion of the secp256k1 permit signature
 */
function claim(
    MintPermit calldata permit,
    address recipient,
    uint8 v,
    bytes32 r,
    bytes32 s
) external payable override {
    require(
        permit.kickoff <= block.timestamp &&
            permit.deadline >= block.timestamp,
        "CALM: permit period invalid"
    );

    //address 0 as recipient in the permit means anyone can claim it
    if (permit.recipient != address(0)) {
        require(
            recipient == permit.recipient,
            "CALM: recipient does not match permit"
        );
    }

    address signer = requireValidMintPermit(permit, v, r, s);

    if (permit.currency == address(0)) {
        require(
            msg.value >= permit.minimumPrice,
            "CALM: transaction value under minimum price"
        );

        (bool success, ) = permit.payee.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed.");
    } else {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(permit.currency);
        token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, signer, permit.minimumPrice);
    }

    _mint(signer, permit.tokenId);

    _thisAsOperator.safeTransferFrom(signer, recipient, permit.tokenId);
}
```

Relevant Code:

```
before(async () => {
    signer = (await ethers.getSigners())[0]
    CALM721Factory = await ethers.getContractFactory("CALM721");
    CALM721Deployment = await CALM721Factory.deploy("CALM", "$CALM");
    const { address } = await CALM721Deployment.deployed();
    contract = CALM721Deployment.connect(address, signer);
});
it("should be able to claim a lazy mint", async () => {
    const metadata = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(NFTMetadata[0]), 'utf-8')
    const tokenId = computeTokenIdFromMetadata(metadata, signer.address)
    const minimumPrice = ethers.utils.parseEther("0").toString()
    const permit = await getMintPermitForId(tokenId, signer, contract, { minimumPrice: minimumPrice })
    const { r, s, v } = ethers.utils.splitSignature(permit.signature)
    const buyer = (await ethers.getSigners())[0]
    const buyerContract = CALM721Deployment.connect(signer, buyer);
    try {
        const creatorEtherBalanceBeforeClaim = await signer.getBalance()
        const buyerEtherBalanceBeforeClaim = await buyer.getBalance()
        const tx = await buyerContract.claim(permit.signedData.message, buyer.address, v, r, s, { value: minimumPrice });
```

Everything appears to work, until I try to claim. (Last Line)

```
console.dir(contract)
```

reveals:

> signer: VoidSigner {
> _isSigner: true,
> address: '0xFD471836031dc5108809D173A067e8486B9047A3',

which is the contract address, not the original signer contract above, nor the buyer.

I've tried so many different mutations of connect and claim parameters, I can't remember everything that's been done.

Any pointers in the right direction will be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In here the signer for any method called to the contract should be the signer object instead of its address.

Your code:

```
try {
    const creatorEtherBalanceBeforeClaim = await signer.getBalance()
    const buyerEtherBalanceBeforeClaim = await buyer.getBalance()
    const tx = await buyerContract.claim(permit.signedData.message, buyer.address, v, r, s, { value: minimumPrice });
```

In here, replace in the tx line "buyer.address" with "buyer" like so:

```
    try {
    const creatorEtherBalanceBeforeClaim = await signer.getBalance()
    const buyerEtherBalanceBeforeClaim = await buyer.getBalance()
    const tx = await buyerContract.claim(permit.signedData.message, buyer, v, r, s, { value: minimumPrice });
```

That should solve the VoidSigner error msg..
Hope this helps.

Comment: Use the signer.getAddress() method whenever you need to use the address as an input. For example, if you need to get the balance of an user using a contract function such as balanceOf(address), replace the address with the output of signer.getAddress(). If you need to perform actions with that "signer" use the signer object.

Comment: Ding Ding Ding.  We have a winner.   Thank you SOOO much.    Now maybe I can grow back some of the hair pulled out over this.  :)

Comment: Looks like may have accepted too soon.  :(   I get this:  Error: invalid address or ENS name (argument="name", value="<SignerWithAddress 0x70...79C8>"...   buyer object:  SignerWithAddress {                                  
  _isSigner: true,                                                                                                                                                                     
  address: '0x70...9C8',

Comment: that looks like the opposite - passing an Object when expecting a simple address. so maybe your code was closer before. did you ever solve this?